# SQL query alternate for "group by" clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL table as:

[image: Screenshot of data in table]

I want to get all the "Name" for some particular DataID and I do not want to use group by as my database is very large.

Comment: A where clause like mr eclair suggested looks like a good answer, but also note that using a group by does not have to perform bad. In your case the field DataID could be a key field, thus sql server is able to use the index for its grouping and thus perform very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use where clause?

```
SELECT Name
from   TableName
where  DataId = 211;
```